# Makefile to pass all arguments to another file

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, sh

I have a `bin/test.sh` file that I call from my makefile:

```
test:
    bin/test.sh
```

I like to pass ALL arguments (i.e. `$@`) to my test file so if I were to do `make test -a arg1 -b arg2 -c arg3 -d` my test file would get all of `-a arg1 -b arg2 -c arg3 -d`.

I don't want to define all of these arguments manually in test file; I just want to pass everything!

Answer (score 3):

`make` is invoked with a list of options followed by a list of targets.

So your example commandline will most likely gives errors about:

- undefined options `-a` and `-c`
- no rule to build targets `arg1`, `arg2`, etc

I think about the closest to what you seem to be asking for will be something like:

```
TEST_ARGS='-a arg1 -b arg2 -c arg3 -d' make test
```

with a Makefile containing:

```
test:
    bin/test.sh $(TEST_ARGS)
```